# WPF possibility to show text and pictures

Tags: wpf, text, image

I'm searching for a possibility to show text and pictures in one wpf element.
Is there a WPF control that I can do this?
Or gives it other options for that?

At the moment I use a simple textbox to show text but now should I show in one box text and pictures.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any place you put a textbox, you can instead put a container control (for example a StackPanel) and in that container you can put any number of controls, for example an Image and a TextBlock

Answer (score 2):

```
     <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding ImageSource}" Width="55"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
     </Grid>
```

Try this out..hopefully there is a View Model which can furnish the two properties ImageSource and Name